# Calculate From different Double number

Tags: java, function, double

i have question about how to calculate from different double

for example

i have 3 type of double data

```
price (x, y, z)
    1. Double type1 = 1.67876
    2. Double type2 = 129.789
    3.Double type3 = 1278.79
```

i want calculate like reduction all the double type using 10 for the 2digit last number after comma so for example
if after comma have 5digits the function will be

for example

```
Double returnX = type1-0.00010;
```

if after comma have 3digits the function will be

```
Double returnY = type2-0.010;
```

if after comma have 2digits the function will be

```
Double returnY = type3-0.10;
```

so how to make the logic for that ?

Comment: Since you mentioned price, you shouldn't use double for currency.  You should use int, long, or BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

It may be implemented like this:

```
static double reduce(double x) {
    double res = x;
    String s = "" + x;
    int posDot = s.indexOf(".");
    if (posDot > -1) {
        int fractionWidth = s.length() - posDot - 1;
        double reduceAmount = 1;
        while (fractionWidth-- > 1) {
            reduceAmount *= 0.1;
        }
        res = x - reduceAmount;
    }
    return res;
}
```